# Iterator reports only last inpust shapefile - Merging multiple shapefiles into a single geodatabase feature class

Tags: arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration, personal-geodatabase

]I have 10 shapefiles in source folder.

I made a model, which use iterator **iterate feature classes** and tool the **feature class to feature**.

I would like to merge multiple shapefiles into a single geodatabase feature class.

Problem is, that gdb contain only last shapefile and not all in the source folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "join all the shapefiles"? Are you joining fields or appending rows?

Comment: You have this tagged with `personal-geodatabase` which was an 8.x format which now unavailable in Pro. Do you really mean file geodatabase?

Comment: but the result in the end is not one feature but as many as the number of input shapefiles. I would like the result to be a feature that combines all input shapefiles in one gdb.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to merge all shapefiles into one feature class in one file geodatabase this model should work. All shapefiles need to have the same geometry type, for example all points, all lines, all polygons.

- Iterate feature classes with your shapefile folder as workspace. (All shapefiles have to be the same geometry type, for example polygons, so i choose geometry type POLYGON in the iterator)
- Collect values will create a list of all shapefiles
- Merge them and save the output in a file geodatabase

[image]